# "corrupted size vs. prev_size" in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector, c-strings

I'm a beginner trying to create a program that will reformat data in a .bat file to something readable. This is for a class and we are not allowed to use #string so I'm using #cstring.

I keep getting the "corrupted size vs. prev_size" error. After doing some research I tried modifying my array sizes but that did not help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct EntryStruc { // structure of cstrings
    char date[13];
    char temp[7];
    char year[5];
    char month[3];
    char day[3];
    char time[5];
    char unit[2];
    char degreesChar[4];
    double degreesDoub;
};

void formatDate(EntryStruc& entry);
void convertTemp(EntryStruc& entry);

int main() {
    int entryQuantity; // integer for quantity of entries
    int tempAverage; // integer for average temp of all entries
    int tempSum; // integer for average temp of all entries

    // defining file stream objects
    ifstream itest;
    ofstream otest;

    // opening the files
    itest.open("itest.bat");
    if (!itest) {
        cout << "\nError: Input file did not open successfully.";
        itest.close();
        return 2; // terminate
    }
    otest.open("otest.bat");
    if (!otest) {
        cout << "\nError: Output file did not open successfully.";
        otest.close();
        return 2; // terminate
    }


    // create vector of entries of the given size
    itest >> entryQuantity;
    vector<EntryStruc> entries(entryQuantity);

    // function calls & fout for each entry
    for (int i=1; i<=entryQuantity; i++) {
        itest >> entries[i].date;
        formatDate(entries[i]);
        itest >> entries[i].temp;
        convertTemp(entries[i]);

        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed
             << entries[i].degreesDoub << " C --- recorded on "
             << entries[i].month << "/"
             << entries[i].day << "/"
             << entries[i].year << " at "
             << entries[i].time << endl;
    }
    itest.close();
    otest.close();
    return 0;
}

void formatDate(EntryStruc& entry) {
    // I opted to brute force the formatting.
    entry.year[0] = entry.date[0];
    entry.year[1] = entry.date[1];
    entry.year[2] = entry.date[2];
    entry.year[3] = entry.date[3];
    entry.month[0] = entry.date[4];
    entry.month[1] = entry.date[5];
    entry.day[0] = entry.date[6];
    entry.day[1] = entry.date[7];
    entry.time[0] = entry.date[8];
    entry.time[1] = entry.date[9];
    entry.time[2] = entry.date[10];
    entry.time[3] = entry.date[11];
}
void convertTemp(EntryStruc& entry) {
    // checking if temp is negative
    // & setting the degrees
    if (entry.temp[1]=='-') {
        entry.degreesChar[0] = entry.temp[2];
        entry.degreesChar[1] = entry.temp[3];
        entry.degreesChar[2] = entry.temp[4];
        entry.degreesChar[3] = entry.temp[5];
    }
    else {
        entry.degreesChar[0] = entry.temp[1];
        entry.degreesChar[1] = entry.temp[2];
        entry.degreesChar[2] = entry.temp[3];
        entry.degreesChar[3] = entry.temp[4];
    }
    // converting entry.degreesChar[] to a double
    double temp = atof(entry.degreesChar);

    // setting the units
    entry.unit[0] = entry.temp[0];

    // checking if temp is F or C
    switch (entry.unit[0]) {
      case 'C':
        break;
      case 'F':
        temp = ((temp-32)/1.8);
        break;
      default:
        cout << "\nError: Temperature unit is not accepted.";
    }
    entry.degreesDoub = temp;
}
```

This is what my itest.bat looks like:

```
2
200807211245 F70.5
200708220812 C19.97
```

Comment: `for (int i=1; i<=entryQuantity; i++)` is wrong - need `for (int i=0; i<entryQuantity; i++)`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).